# CMD - Asking the user to select a path to copy to

Tags: cmd, directory, root

I'm currently using this code to ask the user to select a path to copy to.
I encountered one problem, it does keep the root but not the folder.
I've seleceted `F:\test`, the file was copied to `F:\` (test is an existing file).

How can i solve that !?!?!?

```
setlocal

set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'Please choose a folder.',0,0).self.path""

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "folder=%%I"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Destination Folder choosen
endlocal

copy %userprofile%\downloads\test.txt
```

Comment: You're not even using your %folder% var and are passing no destination to the copy command...

Comment: Google doesn't have anything about asking a user for a directory path for copying?

Comment: it's seems that no mather what i choose the file are copied to the first path i choose... i'm a beginner i've made shearch on google but i need explanation

Comment: The first time i run it i've choose F:\
Now everytime i try it goes to F:\

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to QuickFix (could have been more specific but thanks anyway)

I've added the %folder% at the end of my copy
copy %userprofile%\downloads\test.txt %folder%

and it's working just fine !